# How to implement sigmoid function in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
sigmoid(x) = 1/(1+e(-x))
```

where -x should be in superscript. Without using numpy package, how to write the code to compute this value in Python? For example:

s = 1 / (1 + e(-x))

Suppose is the variable to receive the computation. I am learning Python.

Comment: `import math; 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))`

Comment: It's very Nice.